# How to make promise/callback on forEach loop with async code

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise

I think that I'm looking for promise but I don't see how to use it in my case. 
I would like to `console.log('ended')` only when all my async code is done.
 I have a callback for the DZ.api but not for `forEach()`, what is the best way for doing that ?

```
    _.forEach(filteredTracks, function(n) {
        DZ.api('/playlist/'+ n.id +'/tracks', function(response) {
            _.forEach(response.data, function(n) {
                SP.api('/search/'+n.title, function(response) {
                    console.log(response);
                });
            });
        });
    });
    console.log('ended');
```

Comment: You're looking for [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) -> `Promise.all(arrayOfPromise).then(function (result) {})`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) -> `Promise.all(arrayOfPromise).then(function (result) {})`

With your current code, if SP.api is already Promise compatible, just do :

```
_.map(filteredTracks, function(n) {
    return DZ.api('/playlist/'+ n.id +'/tracks')
            .then(function (response) {
                _.map(response.data, function(n) {
                    return SP.api('/search/'+n.title);
                });

                return Promises.all(response.data);
            });
    });
});

Promise.all(filteredTracks)
    .then(function (results) {
        console.log('ended');
    });
```

If SP.api and DZ Api does not return a Promise you can :

[Promisify](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/API.md#promisepromisifyfunction-nodefunction--dynamic-receiver---function) SP.api DZ Api and and use the same code I wrote before

Or return promises in the ._map

```
_.map(filteredTracks, function(n) {
    var promise = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        DZ.api('/playlist/'+ n.id +'/tracks', function (response) {
                _.map(response.data, function(n) {
                    var insidePromise = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
                        return SP.api('/search/'+n.title, function (result) {
                            resolve(result);
                        });
                    })

                    return insidePromise;
                });

                resolve(Promises.all(response.data));
            });
        });
    });

    return promise;
});

Promise.all(filteredTracks).then(function (results) {
        console.log('ended');
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

What you want is to replace `forEach` with `map` and have each call return a Promise, concatenating the results of the inner loop since you have two levels. Then you pass the array of Promises to `Promise.all()`, which creates a Promise that resolves when all the Promises in the array have resolved. To do that, you'll have to refactor your code to return a Promises from that `DZ.api` function instead of using a callback. In short:

```
let promises = filteredTracks.map(track => {
    return DZ.promisedApi(track).then(response => {
        return Promise.all(response.data.map(n => SP.promisedApi(n))
    }) 
})

Promise.all(promises).then(() => console.log("done!"))
```

Answer (score 1):

You did not specify what libraries you are using but overall I can recommend you to save the promises of all API calls into an array and then using Promises.all()

So you would have something like (WARNING: untested code, just for reference):

```
var promisesArray = []

_.forEach(filteredTracks, function(n) {
    DZ.api('/playlist/'+ n.id +'/tracks', function(response) {
        _.forEach(response.data, function(n) {
            promisesArray.push( SP.api('/search/'+n.title, function(response) {
                console.log(response);
            }));
        });
    });
});

Promise.all(promisesArray)
        .then(function(value){
          console.log('ended');
        })
```

Basically, as stated on the [Promise reference page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all), Promise.all creates a new Promise that resolves when all promises passed as a parameter are resolved. Which in my opinion matches your use case.